# How to fix "ICU Syntax Error: Expected > "identifier" but found "0"." error in Flutter 3.7.0

Tags: flutter, dart, messageformat

After Updating to Flutter 3.7.0 i get this error message when i build my App:

> [app_en.arb:scanCode_fieldNotMatched] ICU Syntax Error: Expected
> "identifier" but found "0".
> field to match is "{0}"

It seems as if something had changed in how the variables are written in the .arb localization files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### UPDATE 1: Escape syntax characters!

If what you are trying is to use the characters `{`, `}`, `'` (or any other syntax character for that matter) in your strings, then you will have to escape them. To do that enable the `use-escaping` flag by adding the following to *l10n.yaml*

```
use-escaping: true
```

Now use pairs of single quotes to escape syntax characters, like "{". To escape single quotes you just have to write it as a double-single quote as follows:

```
{
  "some_text": "Using the '{' character '{isn''t}' trivial?"
}
```

More details on this in the [flutter docu](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization#escaping-syntax).

---

### Update 2: If you are using a Chinese Mirror for Flutter

Follow details in [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/119435).

---

### Original answer to my punctual problem

I found out that the reason for this error is that in **Flutter 3.7**

> Internationalization support has been completely revamped! [they]’ve completely rewritten the gen-l10n tool...

as stated in a [release post](https://medium.com/flutter/whats-new-in-flutter-3-7-38cbea71133c).

---

Previously i was declaring strings in my *.arb* file as follows

```
"scanCode_fieldNotMatched": "field to match is \"{0}\"",
```

where afterwards i was replacing `{0}` by some other value.

Well, it seems that now the `gen-l10n` tool takes what is between brackets as special parameters, and the name `"0"` is not accepted so i had to change my string to

```
"scanCode_fieldNotMatched": "field to match is \"{value0}\"",
```

and `AppLocalizations` can be now called as:

```
AppLocalizations.of(context)!.scanCode_fieldNotMatched("something here to replace value0!")
```

Further details on this can be found here: [Placeholders, plurals, and selects in Flutter](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization#placeholders-plurals-and-selects).

Comment: Do you have an idea how you would have curly brackets in the translation? E.g. the use case of "allowed characters in a password". We would have something like `...=|\\(){}[]...` but this is not allowed anymore since we have `{}` in there

Comment: sadly this doesn't fix it because in their sample arb file doesn't have  \"{0}\"",

Comment: @AxisStarstreamer, to learn how to escape syntax characters please check my updated answer (Update 1).

Comment: @zakiblacki, if you are using Flutter China mirror maybe the "Update 2" to my answer could help you.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, it was due to a translation string in my `arb` file for `intl` package. I had:

`"{x, plural, =1{item}, other{items}}"` (worked fine in previous versions)

This broke in Flutter 3.7. The solution for me was removing a comma:

`"{x, plural, =1{item} other{items}}"` (works in Flutter 3.7)